# How to express y in $y^{x} = e^{\sin x}$ through natural logarithm?

Tags: logarithms

is it possible to express $y$ in this expression:

$y^{x} = e^{\sin x}$

through natural logarithm or, maybe, something else, so we get rid of $y$ at all?

I need to have "something in power of $x$" instead of $e^{\sin x}$ , but I am not sure if it is possible at all.

Comment: Raise both sides to the $\frac 1x$ power.

Comment: so, $y = e^{\frac{\sin x}{x}}$ ?

Comment: Not so quick. You need to address domain

Comment: @imranfat what do you mean?

Comment: In your first equation, x=0 is allowed, in your edit equation,  it's not.

Comment: @imranfat If the thing should define $y$ as a function of $x$, certainly $x=0$ is not allowed. *After the fact*, the function can be extended by continuity at $x=0$.

Comment: @egreg. True, but the OP did not allude to any of that. I think it is important.

Comment: @imranfat yes, I see this problem now. Actually, I am trying to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{\sin 3x} - e^{\sin x}}{x}$ and was hoping that this transformation can help. Now I'm not so sure...

Comment: @Xentai That's a simple derivative, isn't it? $3e^{\sin x}\cos3x-e^{\sin x}\cos x$ evaluated at $0$ yields $3-1=2$.

Comment: @egreg I was trying to find the limit using just knowledge that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a^{x}-1}{x}=\ln(a)$, without using derivatives.

Comment: @Xentai I see; not really the best way, but it can be done. See edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of $y$ can be computed from the value of $x$ if and only if $x\ne0$. So you can safely raise to $1/x$ both sides.

$$
y=\exp\Bigl(\frac{\sin x}{x}\Bigr)
$$

Then this function *can* be extended by continuity at $x=0$.

---

If you want to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{\sin3x}-e^{\sin x}}{x}
$$
do first
$$
l_k=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{\sin(kx)}-1}{x}
$$
by substituting $y=e^{\sin(kx)}-1$, so you get
$$
\lim_{y\to0}\frac{ky}{\arcsin\log(1+y)}=
\lim_{y\to0}\frac{ky}{\log(1+y)}\frac{\log(1+y)}{\arcsin\log(1+y)}=k
$$
Then your limit is $l_3-l_1=3-1=2$.

Comment: Yes, that's a much better way of putting it.